# how to call `getattr()` to get a Python MySQLCursor method?

Tags: python, mysql

What do I need to do do before, to make this Python call succeed:

```
>>>getattr(MySQLCursor, "fetchall")
```

If I just make this call at the beginning of a script, it fails.  I have a cursor and I need to programmatically obtain one of it's methods, such as `fetchall()` from the string, such as `"fetchall"`  I don't understand how to setup this call so it succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getattr(MySQLCursor, "fetchall")` does work:

```
>>> from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
>>> getattr(MySQLCursor, 'fetchall')
<unbound method MySQLCursor.fetchall>
```

So there it is, an unbound method within the *class* MySQLCursor.

If you have an *instance* of the cursor, then you can get a bound method, which you can call:

```
>>> from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor
>>> cursor = MySQLCursor()
>>> cursor
<mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor object at 0x7f9368a86350>
>>> getattr(cursor, 'fetchall')
<bound method MySQLCursor.fetchall of <mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor object at 0x7f9368a86350>>
>>> getattr(cursor, 'fetchall')()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an *instance* of `MySQLCursor`. `MySQLCursor` is a `type` object of its own, so it doesn't actually have that method attributed to it yet as such:

```
>>> type(MySQLCursor)
<class 'type'>
>>> hasattr(MySQLCursor, 'fetchall')  # Not bound to an instance.
False
```

Therefore, you must do something like the below to make it work:

```
example = MySQLCursor()
getattr(obj, 'fetchall')
```

Comment: Which `type` would that be ?

Comment: @AlexThornton - I find that `getattr` (and `hasattr`) work. Is there a particular version that you are using?

Comment: @mhawke I didn't test it with that specific class. I whipped up a class quickly in an IDE and observed that behaviour, so I put it in my answer assuming it would work the same way (incorrect?). Using Python 3.3

Comment: I thought it was of type `str`,etc.. Not the `type` object itself.

Comment: @d-coder when you create a `class`, you create a _new_ `type`.

Comment: @AlexThornton I misunderstood it. Now it's clear. Thanks